# Qt Documentation Standards

Tags: qt, documentation, qt-creator, doxygen

I am looking for some help regarding documenting code in Qt. For instance, when I am developing on the XNA platform I use XML notation with tags such as summary, params, etc. What does Qt have and what are some standards.

In addition, I am looking for something that will work with documentation generating applications (such as Doxygen), unless Qt has something better that I don't know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt internally uses [QDoc](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/pages/DocManual), which is not a supported product. It is similar to doxygen. If you already know doxygen, you should use it to document your Qt projects. See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776388/qt-style-documentation-using-doxygen).